# select from table not in php array query not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I get an array to string conversion warning when I try to select using my `$name_array` variable in the `NOT IN` clause. I have tried loads of different quotation combinations, but I either get a syntax error or an array to string conversion warning. can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks.

```
$db->query("SELECT contactname
            FROM contacts 
            WHERE contactname 
            NOT IN (' . implode(",", $name_array) . ')
          ");
```

Comment: You need quotes around the names: `in ('john','peter','jack')`

Comment: $db->query("SELECT contactname
            FROM contacts 
            WHERE contactname 
            NOT IN ('" . implode(",", $name_array) . "')
          ");
implode should be out of the quotes

Comment: @ManZzup: That won't work.

Comment: I put the quotation marks around the array variable but I still get the array to string warning

Comment: @user2014429: You need to add the quotes around every single name and not around all of them.

Comment: @ juergen if you mean about quotes yeah it need quotes as well, but should fix the error in concatenation as well

Comment: Your quotes don't match: you start with double quotes, but end with single quotes before the concatenation.

Comment: what's the `var_dump($name_array);` output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put quotes around each name before imploding them into a list.

```
$names = implode(",", array_map(function($x) { return "'$x'"; }, $name_array));
$db->query("SELECT contactname
            FROM contacts 
            WHERE contactname 
            NOT IN ($names)
          ");
```

Comment: I tried this and I really thought it would work because it seems to solve the problem of the quotation marks for the indexes. But for some reason I'm still getting the blasted array to string warning. But still +1 because it should have solved the problem.

Comment: UPDATE - there was something unrelated which was preventing it from working, now the code works great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You have to quote name in '' due to string so please use.

```
$val="'";
$val.=implode("','",$name_array);
$val.="'";
$db->query("SELECT contactname FROM contacts WHERE contactname NOT IN ($val) ");
```

This will defiantly help you

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
$db->query("SELECT contactname
            FROM contacts 
            WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(contactname, \'' . implode(",", $name_array) . '\')   
          ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$db->query("SELECT contactname
            FROM contacts 
            WHERE contactname 
            NOT IN ('".implode("','",$name_array).'\')');
```